# conform equality constraints

Tags: java, generics

I wrote some generic method. It works fine with first-level descendants. But it fails with objects of the second-level descendant.

```
package com.company;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int f(List<T> list, T item) {
        return 0;
    }

    static class A implements Comparable<A> {
        @Override
        public int compareTo(A o) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    static class B extends  A {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<A> as = new ArrayList<A>();
        List<B> bs = new ArrayList<B>();
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B();

        f(as, a); // works
        f(bs, b); // <-------- error
    }
}
```

Compilation fails with:
Error:(29, 9) java: method f in class com.company.Main cannot be applied to

```
given types;
  required: java.util.List<T>,T
  found: java.util.List<com.company.Main.B>,com.company.Main.B
  reason: inferred type does not conform to equality constraint(s)
    inferred: com.company.Main.A
    equality constraints(s): com.company.Main.A,com.company.Main.B
```

Why Java can not guess the equality variable types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type parameter `T` of your function `f`, has to implement `Comparable<T>` as per your definition `<T extends Comparable<T>>`. `B` does *not* implement `Comparable<B>`, but rather `Comparable<A>`. When you want to be able to call the function with `B`, the class should implement `Comparable<B>`, e.g. like so

```
static class B extends A implements Comparable<B> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(B o) {
        return super.compareTo(o);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, you could change the type parameter of `f` to be able to have `T`s which are subclasses of a `Comparable` class.

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> int f(List<T> list, T item) {
    return 0;
}
```